# getting issue in download pdf convert from jpg,png image

Tags: php, wordpress, fpdf

I am trying to convert JPG and PNG images to PDF, I'm using FPDF17 library. I had change permission from 777 to 755 and check website hosting FPDF is enable. However I'm getting problem when downloading PDF.

**I used function below:**

```
$a = getimagesize($file);
```

I'm getting this warnnig:

```
    **Warning: getimagesize(../uploads/2016/03/69682233_newsletter_erfolgreich.jpg): failed to open stream: Connection refused in /mnt/nfs/www/../includes/controllers/lib/pdf/fpdf17/fpdf.php on line 1213

FPDF error: Missing or incorrect image file: ../wp-content/uploads/2016/03/69682233_newsletter_erfolgreich.jpg**
```

Comment: Use the full path to that file and make sure it exists.

Comment: yes it already exist. i can access the file from ftp and cpanel. path is also correct.
i can see the path in backend also

Comment: You used relative path, not full path.

Comment: i have use website full path like webiste url to image but i have getting same error

Comment: Your full path should start from `/mnt/nfs/www/` and so on to the file

Comment: okay you mean i have to use full path like /mnt/nfs/www.xyz.com/wp-conetnt/upload/2016/03/abc.jpg  ??

Comment: Exactly, that's what I meant to say. Have you tried?

Comment: yes its working.....Thank You !

Comment: Thanks for help me in jpg file downlaod

when i png image download for pdf then i have gettong below error

 **fopen(/mnt/nfs/www/../htdocs/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/logo_brillen_de_gross-5-e1457180990650.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /mnt/nfs/www/../wp-content/themes/wpgroupbuy/core/includes/controllers/lib/pdf/fpdf17/fpdf.php on line 1244**
 
`$f = fopen($test1,'rb');
 
 if(!$f)
  $this->Error('Can\'t open image file1: '.$test1);
 $info = $this->_parsepngstream($f,$test1);
 fclose($f);
 return $info;`
    

 getting fpdf error